# 2012 Toyota Camry LE 2.5L SFI DOHC 4cyl missing sensor connector

Tags: toyota, camry

https://kodieh40.imgur.com/

I pulled the sensor to see if it had any identifying marks. It does, E 5 NA8. But that didn't bring anything up for me. The car is throwing P0013 which is P0013 - "B" Camshaft Position Actuator Circuit (Bank 1) but "Cam Shaft Position Sensor Connector" didn't get me the right connector from the dealership. Engine is the sensor in place, Engine 2 is the sensor out with identifying marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the dealer for the oil control valve connector. That's not the camshaft sensor.

90980-11162 should be the part number.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I need to bookmark this site, Reddit was less helpful.

Comment: @KodieHill updated with a part number.

Comment: Hey, I just got the part in. The wires from the wiring harness are gray and red, but the wires I got were white. Does it matter which way I splice the wires?

Comment: @KodieHill I didn't see a connector end view but generally while looking at the connector from the back tab up pin 1 is on the left. pin 1 is red.

Comment: I was gonna inbox you, but I cant find a way. I was hoping this was going to fix my issue but it hasn't. The Sensor was out for several months, and so I figured it was going to solve the problem of operating at high RPMs (2k@70 MPH) and the engine dying when coming to anything but a slow stop. It fixed the dying problem, but its still operating at high RPMs and has a weird time when it's cold shifting properly. Once warmed up, it does fine. Would this oil control valve being not connected throw the engine timing off? I've seen that this problem could be an O2 sensor? Just looking for thoughts.

Comment: @KodieHill make sure your trans fluid is ok. also try disconnecting the battery and shorting the cables together for a few minutes and see if the transmission will relearn the shift tables.